# Is there a notable set of polyhedra with 16 members?

Tags: polyhedra

So [Platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid) have five members, [Archimedean  Solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_solid) have 13. I was wondering if there was any notable and/or famous set of polyhedra that either has precisely 16 or, if that is not possible, then $2^n$ members.

Comment: The sets should be interesting for what they are, not for how many elements are in them.

Comment: I am aware. I Just asked whether some set happens to fulfill this particular and arbitrary property about its cardinality.

Comment: Why, many do. You may take a basket and grab the first 16 polyhedra you'll see, that will be a set all right. Whether it will have anything interesting about it, though, is hard to tell. Chances are it won't.

Comment: That is the very reason why I asked about a *notable* set of polyhedra. That is, a set that is famous and important for other particularities but just so happen to have such amount of members.

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't notice the word "notable" in the title, sorry about that. Well, I don't know of such family off the top of my head. There are 32 [crystallographic point groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_point_group), but these are not quite the same as polyhedra (though not entirely unrelated either).

Comment: That is fine. I just realized that even though the word "notable" is present um the title, it does not show in the body of the question. So I will l edit it.